# Homoscedasticity in regression model building example

Tags: regression, linear-model, heteroscedasticity

In a linear model building example for a class, we are given a data set and told to use methods like forward, backward, and stepwise selection to choose predictors to include. I get to a combination of terms that I feel comfortable using in the model and provide decent adjusted $R_a^2$ value: 0.8459. The residuals show constant variance at this point. The following are the residuals: 
[image]

The exercise then prompts to add any interaction terms that I feel may be necessary. I added an interaction term that is the squared value of one of the predictors after centering the predictor. I come to the conclusion to the term based on plots against the response variable and a general linear test. I have strong evidence to include the interaction term; however when I add the term the residual variance loses its constancy. It now resembles: [image]

The  $R_a^2$ value is now 0.9096. I clearly see a change and run the Breusch-Pagan (p-value = 0.219) test which I knew would confirm this visual of loss of homoscedasticity. I feel that this is only a small departure though. I am looking for advice on determining how bad the departure from constant error variance needs to be before I decide on another model. What are the implications of keeping a model that only moderately violates this?

Note: I know the $R_a^2$ isn't the sole basis of why I think this model is better; I was given evidence through other tests that the interaction term should have been in the model.

Note: The normality assumption of residuals was not violated throughout. A log transformation was already performed on the response variable for both models in question.

Comment: When you performed predictor selection, you did not include the interaction term. If the actual model were "y = a * X1 * X2", your preliminary selection work would yield a model of "y = aX1 + bX2". If after that you additionally included an interaction term for X1 * X2, the final model would be "y = aX1 + bX2 + cX1X2" which (in my example) is incorrect.

Comment: I was under the impression that if you included a higher order term you must keep the lower order terms that formed the higher order predictor. Correct me if I am wrong: you are saying this is incorrect? Can you point me to something I can read to help me understand why that is true. I am looking at my notes and it seems that it is the exact opposite. @JamesPhillips

Comment: Good question. If the true model were "y = x^2", and you first found "y = a + bx', then adding a term for x^2 would make the model "y = a + bx + cx^2" which (in my example) would be incorrect. My point is that the interaction terms you mention in your question should be part of the initial predictor selection process.